# Extending Domino Designer 9.0.1 in Eclipse - which plugins are required?

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm working on an open source project to make a plugin for Domino Designer 9.0.1.

Does anyone know the required com.ibm.? plugins necessary ? In 8.5.2 the plugins were

```
com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.commons
com.ibm.designer.domino.ide.resources
```

But I can't find their equivalent for 9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There the same. I was not setting up correctly. Thanks to Ralf Petter.